# Sql select where array in column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause, where-in

In my query I use join table `category_attributes`. Let's assume we have such rows:

```
category_id|attribute_id
1|1
1|2
1|3
```

I want to have the query which suites the two following needs. I have a variable (php) of allowed `attribute_id's`. If the array is subset of `attribute_id` then `category_id` should be selected, if not - no results.

First case:

```
select * from category_attributes where (1,2,3,4) in category_attributes.attribute_id
```

should give no results.

Second case

```
select * from category_attributes where (1,2,3) in category_attributes.attribute_id
```

should give all three rows (see dummy rows at the beginning).

So I would like to have reverse side of what standard SQL `in` does.

Comment: Can more than one row have the same `attribute_id`? If so, how do you decide which `category_id` to return?

Comment: @Nick Actually yes. But I have very complex query. I will not use select directly. I just need `where` part. The whole query has `join` on `category_id`. So according to my estimate, after join the result will look like the provided dummy table. I need to filter that table. I tried right join, different where's, subquery. I have no clue how to perform my task.

Comment: It is very surprising to know that this question hasn't asked before.

Comment: @Anees For me it was more surprising that I was downvoted twice. Have not clue why. However agree. I got thinking that I do things in wrong way. However no one suggested any simple solution.

Comment: That may be because this question looks silly at first glance. But is valid or even interesting actually (You've got my +1). There should have been a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

**Step 1:** Group the data by the field you want to check.

**Step 2:** Left join the list of required values with the records obtained in the previous step.

**Step 3:** Now we have a list with required values and corresponding values from the table.  The second column will be equal to required value if it exist in the table and `NULL` otherwise.

[image: Step 3 output]

Count null values in the right column. If it is equal to 0, then it means table contains all the required values. In that case return all records from the table. Otherwise there must be at least one required value is missing in the table. So, return no records.

### Sample

**Table "Data":**

[image: Table data]

**Required values:**

`10, 20, 50`

**Query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Data 
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   (SELECT D.value 
                FROM   (SELECT 10 AS value 
                        UNION 
                        SELECT 20 AS value 
                        UNION 
                        SELECT 50 AS value) T 
                       LEFT JOIN (SELECT value 
                                  FROM   Data 
                                  GROUP  BY value) D 
                              ON ( T.value = D.value )) J 
        WHERE  value IS NULL) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select ca.category_id
from category_attributes ca
where ca.attribute_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) 
group by ca.category_id
having count(*) = 4;  -- "4" is the size of the list
```

This assumes that the table has no duplicates (which is typical for attribute mapping tables).  If that is a possibility, use:

```
having count(distinct ca.attribute_id) = 4
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, nor am I an expert in SQL. But this doesn't look like it will work since `count(*)`  will count the records grouped together which is equal to 1 if attribute_ids are unique, not how many unique attribute_ids are there.

Comment: @Anees . . . The `COUNT(*)` counts the number of matching categories.  That seems to be exactly what the OP wants.  You are misunderstanding something about SQL and GROUP BY.

Answer (score -1):

You can aggregate `attribute_id` into array and compare two array from php.

```
SELECT category_id FROM 
(select category_id, group_concat(attribute_id) as attributes from category_attributes
order by attribute_id) t WHERE t.attributes = (1, 2, 3);
```

But you need to find another way to compare arrays or make sure that array is always sorted.

Comment: This will not fit the first case. Your `select * from category_attributes where category_attributes.attribute_id in (1,2,3, 4);`  will give all results. I do not want this.

Comment: I know how to use `in`. I have written invented syntax which I need.

Comment: Changed answer. Hope this might help.

Comment: Did you try your query? I got an error `Operand should contain 1 column`

Comment: I managed to run your query (with a little change). However the first case is not implemented. Parameters for the query `(1, 2, 3, 4)` should give no results